# What does a "well ordering on $\Bbb R$" mean?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

A well order is a poset such that every non empty subset of this set has a least element. Does "well ordering on $\Bbb R$" mean that every non empty subset of $\Bbb R$ (which is a poset) has a least element?

Comment: Yes.  Note that it can't be the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$, and indeed it is impossible to construct such an ordering without using some version of the axiom of choice.

Comment: @user10354138 what does the ordering have to do with "having a least element" though? Every subset would be the same no?

Comment: I worry that when you say "$\mathbb{R}$ (which is a poset)", you are automatically thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ as a poset with the usual ordering. However, in the claim "$\mathbb{R}$ admits a well-order", the symbol $\mathbb{R}$ only refers to the *set* of reals, without any further structure. So this claim only says that there is some well-ordering on the set of reals. It says nothing about any kind of compatibility or connection between this well-order and the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It means the same thing as "an enumeration of the rational numbers".

Comment: @halrankard You mean $(ℝ,\preceq)$ and not a specific order like $≤$? I dont get it.. I saw a couple of question on here talking about this and people use for example 0, 1, -1, 2, -2.. to show that the integers are well ordered, but what does this have to do with the well ordering? What is the $\preceq$ in this case?

Comment: Yes, the well-ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ will not be the usual order $\leq$. (Of course, a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ is still a "specific" order in the sense that it is a concrete thing; but it's just not going to be the usual ordering $\leq$ of $\mathbb{R}$ since that's not a well-order.) Unlike the integers, I can't explicitly write down a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ because it's existence involves the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 4):

A well-ordering on $\Bbb R$ is a binary relation $\preceq$ between elements of $\Bbb R$ such that $(\Bbb R,\preceq)$ is well-ordered. I.e. a relation $\preceq$ which is reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive and such that every non-empty subset $S\subseteq\Bbb R$ has an element $x\in S$ such that, for all $y\in S$, $x\preceq y$.

Comment: a well-ordering on $\mathbb R$ is difficult to construct, right?

Comment: Some would say impossible and fortunately no one asked me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a theorem of set theory that every set can be endowed with a well-ordering (*Zermelo's theorem*).

Actually, the *axiom of choice*, *Zorn's lemma* and *Zermelo's theorem* are equivalent.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question, which is what does it mean for the real numbers to be well-ordered.

Comment: I agree, I see it rather as an aside comment. I wanted to insist on the axiom of choice to explain why it is pointless, from my point of view,  to explicit the meaning of a well-order on $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Well, surely with 152,261 points you can leave a comment under the question... :-)